# iOS inter-app communication

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, url-scheme

I am wondering what is considered the most **secure** way of two apps **exchanging data** within **Cocoa Touch env**.

I am very much **new** in iOS development and swift development and I am just looking to explore another part of the OS capabilities.

I read about App Groups sharing a location (directory) where files can be exchanged but also about URL schemas between apps to share data.

Are there any other ways of inter-app data exchange? And which is considered the most **secure** one?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you consider **secure**, but the iOS Keychain may fit your needs. The iOS Keychain is password protected and can be accessed by other applications that you authorize.

Take a look at the official [Keychain Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html) and [this article](http://shaune.com.au/ios-keychain-sharing-data-between-apps/) explain how it works.